# spawn daemon process with make

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, daemon

I'm fiddling with [`libfuse`](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) and I find useful the rules `make mount` which executes the userspace fuse daemon and `make umount` to unmount the directory. Unfortunately if I start the daemon in the `make mount` rule, this gets killed as soon as make exits (when the rule is completed).

Is it possible to spawn a daemon from a make rule such that the daemon persists the exit of make?

Comment: If you "strace" the daemon, does it actually call daemon() or double fork() when executing?  That _should_ detach it from the sub-shell that Make spawns for the make rule.  Perhaps try running "setsid <daemon command>" to manually separate it from the process session?

Answer (score 1):

Make is the wrong tool for the job here. It shouldn't be used as a supervisor for other processes and anything it starts *should* end when it does.

That being said you can easily unhitch processes so that kill signals are not propagated when processes terminate. Running your fuse daemon prefixed by `nohup …` should stop the signals from reaching the child process and it will go on it's merry way.